# Printing a generator object in Python

Tags: python, printing, generator

I'm trying to have access to all elements created by a generator, as per the following code:

```
from itertools import combinations


Fatores = ['Ft', 'Fp', 'Floc']


def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = range(r)
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)

panel = combinations(Fatores,2)
for subset in panel:
    print(subset)
```

However, I'm having the following error message:

TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment

Does anybody have some hint to solve this problem?

Kind Regards

Comment: In older versions of python, `range()` returned a list, but in Python 3, `range()` is its own special type of object.  You can easily convert it to a list with `indices = list(range(r))`.

Comment: Hi John. Your suggestion worked out flawlessly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong is with your code

1.

`if r > n:
        return
    indices = range(r)
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)`

indices assignment should be above return and than return should return just variable

2. yield is used in for loop which is not in your example

i'm not pretty sure what this part try to do but i think above if should be for loop

Comment: Hi Bartek. I've solved it simply adding indices = list(range(r)). Thanks for your message!